# MySQL Query Optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing, query-optimization

I have web application that use a similar table scheme like below. simply I want to optimize the selection of articles. articles are selected based on the tag given. for example, if the tag is 'iphone' , the query should output all open articles about 'iphone' from the last month.

```
CREATE TABLE `article` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`body` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`date` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`author_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`section` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`status` int(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `tags` (
`name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`article_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`name`,`article_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

The following is my MySQL query

```
 explain select article.id,users.username,article.title 
 from article,users,tags 
 where article.id=tags.article_id and tags.name = 'iphone4' 
 and article.author_id=users.id and article.status = '1' 
 and article.section = 'mobile' 
 and article.date > '2010-02-07 13:25:46' 
 ORDER BY tags.article_id DESC
```

the output is

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra <br>
1   SIMPLE  tags    ref     PRIMARY     PRIMARY     92  const   55  Using where; Using index <br>
1   SIMPLE  article     eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   test.tags.article_id    1   Using where <br>
1   SIMPLE  users   eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   test.article.author_id  1     <br>
```

is it possible to optimize it more?

Comment: General rule is to put an index on any field(s) that you use in a join and/or where clause. But until your DB gets very large, *not* having an index on 'tags.name' and 'article.status' and the like isn't going to matter. However, if things do slow down later, it's something to look into.

Answer (score 0):

This query may be optimized, depending on which condition is more selective: `tags.name = 'iphone4'` or `article.date > '2010-02-07 13:25:46'`

If there are less articles tagged `iphone` than those posted after `Feb 7`, then your original query is nice.

If there are many articles tagged `iphone`, but few those posted after `Feb 7`, then this query will be more efficient:

```
SELECT  article.id, users.username, article.title
FROM    tags
JOIN    article
ON      article.id = tags.article_id
        AND article.status = '1'
        AND article.section = 'mobile'
        AND article.date > '2010-02-07 13:25:46'
JOIN    users
ON      users.id = article.author_id
WHERE   tags.name = 'iphone4'
ORDER BY
        tags.article_date DESC, tags.article_id DESC
```

Note that the `ORDER BY` condition has changed. This may or may not be what you want, however, generally the orders of `id` and `date` correspond to each other.

If you really need your original `ORDER BY` condition you may leave it but it will add a `filesort` (or just revert to your original plan).

In either case, create an index on

```
article (status, section, date, id)
```

Answer (score 0):

> the query should output all open articles about 'iphone' from the last month.

So the only query you are going to run on this data uses the tag and the date. You've got a index for the tag in the tags table, but the date is stored in a different table (article - you're a bit inconsistent with your naming schema). Adding an index on the article table using date would be no benefit at all. Using id,date (in that order) would help a little - but really the date needs to be denormalised into the tags table to get the query running really fast.

Unless you're regularly moving around bulk data sets - just add a datetime column with a default of the current timestamp to the tags table.

I expect that you may be wanting to interact with the data in lots of other ways - really you should set a low (no?) threshold for slow query logging then analyse the resulting data to identify where you're performance problems are (try looking at the queries with the highest values for duration^2*frequency first).

There's a script at the URL below which is useful for this analysis:

http://www.retards.org/projects/mysql/

Answer (score -1):

You could index the additional fields in article that you are referencing in your select statement.  In this case, I would suggest you create an index in article like this:

```
CREATE INDEX article_idx ON article (author_id, status, section, date);
```

Creating that index should speed up your query depending on how many  overall records you are dealing with.  From my understanding, properly creating indexes involves looking at the queries you've written and indexing the columns that are a part of your where clause.  This helps the query optimizer better process the query in general.  That does not mean create an index on each individual column, however, as its both inefficient to do so and ineffective.  When possible, create multiple column indexes that represent your select statement.

Comment: The only query usef_ksa has mentioned is using keyword and article date - that query won't the index you suggest.

Comment: In the original question the where clause is specifically looking at all 4 of those fields in article.  Not all 4 are joined to another table, but all 4 are used in the actual query.  Why wouldn't it use that index in the query?  It indexes the remaining fields being queried that are not a part of the primary key.